# word2vec's probalistic output

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I'm new to the world of word2vec and I just start to use gensim's implementation for word2vec.

I use two naive sentences as my first document set,

```
[['first', 'sentence'], ['second', 'sentence']]
```

The vectors I get are like this:

```
'first', -0.07386458, -0.17405555
'second', 0.0761444 , -0.21217766
'sentence', 0.0545655 , -0.07535963
```

However, when I type in another toy document sets:

```
[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```

I get the following result:

```
'a', 0.02936198, -0.05837455
'b', -0.05362414, -0.06813956
'c', 0.11918657, -0.10411404
```

Again, I'm new to word2vec but according to my understanding,
my two document sets are structurally identical, so the results of the corresponding word should be the same.
But why I'm getting different results?
Is the algorithm always giving probalistic output or the document sets too small?

The function I used is as the following:

```
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, size=2, min_count=1, window=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Prime reason you are getting different vectors is random initialisation of vectors in word2vec (there are other reasons like negative sampling, threading which can lead to difference in vector values).

The philosophy behind word2vec being, if the number of documents (training data) >> number of unique words (vocabulary size), the vectors for the words will stabilise after few iterations.